# Kafka Broker SASL - NoAuth Exception - KeeperErrorCode NoAuth for /brokers/ids

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, sasl

I have ended up with below exception on broker 2 and 3 node while implementing SASL_SSL GSSAPI  mechanism for Broker to Zookeper Authentication

From SSL settings, the cluster is configured with SASL_SSL authentication

Broker 1 ran successful but on broker 2 and 3, there is an exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /brokers/ids

Can you please help, what could be the reason for broker to shut down with below exception

Exception:

```
ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /brokers/ids
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:120)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
        at kafka.zookeeper.AsyncResponse.maybeThrow(ZooKeeperClient.scala:564)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createRecursive(KafkaZkClient.scala:1898)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.makeSurePersistentPathExists(KafkaZkClient.scala:1796)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createTopLevelPaths$1(KafkaZkClient.scala:1788)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createTopLevelPaths$1$adapted(KafkaZkClient.scala:1788)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createTopLevelPaths(KafkaZkClient.scala:1788)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:793)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:399)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to your zookeeper, you will find the broker ID missing and get a connection error with the hostname that the zookeeper used. You need to re-create your certs and add the hostname/IPs into your ext file.

It works for me.